# Node.js/Express.js: TypeError: path argument is required to res.sendFile

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am uploading my files using Multer to a directory. Now, I want to download those same files which I have displayed on the HTML in the form of a table with each file having a download option. In doing so, I am getting an error.

Here's my code:

> Express.js

```
//as per the express documentation available

router.get('/downloadfile', (req, res, next) => {

var options = {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './uploads'),
  dotfiles: 'deny',
  headers: {
    'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
    'x-sent': true
  }
}

var fileName = req.params.id3
res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
  if (!err)
  {
    console.log('File sent successfully');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Error occured while sending file.' + err.message)
  }
})
});
```

> Angular

```
onDownloadFiles(i: any)
{
 this.fileToDownload = i;
 console.log(this.fileToDownload);

 const params = new HttpParams().set('id3', this.fileToDownload);
 this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/downloadfile', {params})
 .pipe(map(responseData => {
  return responseData;
 }))
 .subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);

 })
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: path argument is required to res.sendFile
```

Can anybody explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the `originalName` to the callback inside your `filename` function:

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
}
```

Note that this poses a security risk though, you may want to read this: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/439#issuecomment-271105916